# Flutter: show asset gif in alert dialog

Tags: flutter, dialog, gif

I am trying to show this gif asset in my alert dialog, but get an error:

```
Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: assets/tutorial/lip.gif
```

But .png images work fine.

Here is my code for the alert dialog:

```
...
AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Showing Lip'),
        content: Container(
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/tutorial/lip.gif',
            height: 125.0,
            width: 125.0,
          ),
        ),
...
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the right method to display a GIF.

Your problem is probably that the path for the file you trying to display isn't right.

Did you add this file in your `pubspec.yaml` file?
Here's the [official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images) on how to add an asset to your Flutter project

Comment: I just found out what's wrong... I did not rebuild the project but only hot loaded it... After a full rebuild with 'flutter run', everything works fine...